# Get total sum and count of a column in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

Is a nested SELECT statement possible in sql? I'm working on a problem and I can't seem to get the data that I want. This is the sql that Im querying:

```
 SELECT derived.municipality, count(*) as counts, derived.bearing
    from (SELECT m.name as municipality,  count(*) as totalcount, sum(f.no_of_bearing_trees) as bearing 
    from farmer_profile f
    inner join barangay b on f.barangay_id = b.id
    inner join municipality m on b.municipality_id = m.id
    inner join province p on m.province_id = p.id
    group by b.name) as derived
    group by derived.municipality, derived.bearing
```

Here is the sample data im working with. I want to get the sum of all the bearing and total counts when i put a where clause at the bottom (eg. where derived.bearing < 20). All of those bearings with less than 20 will totaled as well as their counts. I'm not sure if a subquery is needed again or not.

[image: l]

Comment: It is unclear to me what your question really is.  Obviously, subqueries are allowed -- you have shown an example.  But what are you trying to do?  What results do you want?

Comment: Sorry for an unclear question. What i am trying to achieve is to add all those similar named data and total their counts and bearings. I tried doing a subquery but the bearing and count always lands a false answer when i try to group by again.

Comment: @Yuugii, to make question clear just show your data and then the result you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want to filter on municipalities whose bearing sum is less than 20. If so, you can use a `having` clause for this:

```
select
    m.name as municipality,  
    count(*) as totalcount, 
    sum(f.no_of_bearing_trees) as bearing 
from farmer_profile f
inner join barangay b on f.barangay_id = b.id
inner join municipality m on b.municipality_id = m.id
inner join province p on m.province_id = p.id
group by b.name
having sum(f.no_of_bearing_trees) < 20
```

MySQL is lax about column aliases in the `having` clause, so you can also do:

```
having bearing < 20
```

Comment: hi and thanks for answering, i did that in my previous trials but it doesn't group up all the municipalities. it just adds up the count and bearings with the same numbers

Comment: @Yuugii: you would probably need to provide sample data and expected results as tabular text to clarify what you really expect. Better yet, you might want to set up a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) so anyone can try their queries against your data.